# SQL Query filter based on another column values without parsing it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would need some help regarding a SQL query that I can't figure out.
I have 2 tables like this:

```
| ID  | NAME   |
| RO1 | Arnold |
| RO2 | Ed     |
| RO3 | Sal    |
| RO4 | Teus   |
.
.
| RO11 | Haus |
```

The second table:

```
| Concat_ID | Concat_Name |
| RO3,RO4   | Teus,Port   |
| RO10, RO15 | Rar,Tar |
| RO2, RO6 | Ed, Kev   |
```

The current methodology is to parse the second table and to replace the filter conditions dinamically based on the rows from the second table:

1st query:

```
select distinct ID,
NAME
from TABLE1
where ID IN ('RO3','RO4')
and NAME IN ('Teus','Port')
```

2st query:

```
select distinct ID,
NAME
from TABLE1
where ID IN ('RO10', 'RO15')
and NAME IN ('Rar','Tar')
```

And so on...

Is there a way to do this with just a single query?

Comment: You mean parse the second table?

Comment: Yes, will modify

Comment: what do you want to do with those 2 tables? I don't understand what you want yet with your example, to be honest

Comment: I want to select all rows from the 1st table which exists in the second, without having to parse the second table is order to dynamically pass the filter values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you could do this:

```
select *
from t1
where exists (
    select *
    from t2
    where exists (
        select *
        from string_split(t2.concat_id, ',')
        where t1.id = value
    ) and exists (
        select *
        from string_split(t2.concat_name, ',')
        where t1.name = value
    )
)
```

Basically each row in t1 is compared with each row in t2; for each combination you check if the t1.id matches one of the comma separated ids **and** t2.name matches one of the comma separated names. `string_split` requires SQL Server 2016 or later.

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6fcccc11a49d5ce12b46b9ed854211f3)